# Why does this query take so long to execute?

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure-sql-database, query-performance

I'm currently using `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8` as the database. The database currently has 10 DTUs.

The idea here is that I want to make the query based on the view. This view contains of simple `SELECT()` syntax with 5 table joins. This view give output roughly about 253K rows in about 6 seconds.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TopAdsDisplaySumaryView]
AS
SELECT  
        client.Id AS ClientId,      -- (PK, int, not null)
        client.PartnerId,           -- (FK, int, not null)
        adsPict.Id AS AdsPictureId, -- (PK, int, not null)
        adsPict.ImageName,          -- (nvarchar(max), null)
        displayAds.DisplayTo,       -- (datetime, not null)
        displayAds.DisplayFrom      -- (datetime, not null)
FROM      
        dbo.Machines AS machine 
        INNER JOIN dbo.MachineGroups AS machineGroups ON machineGroups.Id = machine.MachineGroupId 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Clients AS client ON client.Id = machineGroups.ClientId 
        INNER JOIN dbo.DisplyadAds AS displayAds ON displayAds.MachineId = machine.Id 
        INNER JOIN dbo.AdsPictures AS adsPict ON adsPict.Id = displayAds.AdsPictureId
```

[image]

Notice that I'm only taking the column from tables `clients`, `displayAds`, and `adsPictures`, but I have to join tables `machines` and `machineGroups` in order to get data from `clients`. `displayAds` table has the most data.

From here I want to generate the top 5 data with the most data count. This is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 5
    adsSum.PartnerId as PartnerId,
    adsSum.ClientId as ClientId,
    adsSum.AdsPictureId as AdsPictureId,
    adsSum.ImageName as ImageName,
    count(*) as TotalDisplay
FROM [dbo].[TopAdsDisplaySumaryView] adsSum
GROUP BY adsSum.PartnerId, adsSum.ClientId, adsSum.AdsPictureId, adsSum.ImageName
ORDER BY TotalDisplay DESC
```

Here's the actual execution plan for this query: https://pastebin.com/CcR9cC5e

When this query is executed, it takes about 1 minute 15 seconds. I'm trying to find out why this query takes a lot of time to execute, while executing the view only takes 6 seconds.

Here's my attempts so far:

1. Created an index for `displayAds` table. This gives me ~1 second improvement, no big change.

   ```
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
   [MachineIdIndexIncludeAdsPictureIdDisplayFromDisplayTo] ON [dbo].[DisplyadAds]
   (
       [MachineId] ASC
   )
   INCLUDE 
   (   
       [AdsPictureId],
       [DisplayFrom],
       [DisplayTo]
   )
   GO
   ```
2. Created an index for `adsPictures` table. Nothing changed.

   ```
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AdsPictures_IncludeImageName] ON [dbo].[AdsPictures]
   (
      [Id] ASC
   )
   INCLUDE ( [ImageName])
   GO
   ```
3. Tried to remove column `adsPict.ImageName` in the query, the execution time was greatly improved to only 3 seconds (~72 sec. improvement!). I suspect that column is the problem, but I need it to show.

The maximum record length of `ImageName` is 36. Mostly around 11~20. There are 55 rows in `AdsPictures` table.

Any idea how to resolve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, looks like you might be dealing with out of date statistics, estimated rows 12k, actual 254k.

Comment: @jean, The types of each column are already added in the view. I marked them in comments.

Comment: Nop you don't I talking about things like `ON machineGroups.Id = machine.MachineGroupId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I see in the XML for your actual plan:

```
<WaitStats>
<Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="66883" WaitCount="1649" />
<Wait WaitType="RESOURCE_GOVERNOR_IDLE" WaitTimeMs="56086" WaitCount="3980" />
</WaitStats>
<QueryTimeStats CpuTime="6665" ElapsedTime="73522" />
```

You can also see this information in the root node of the plan in SSMS if you don't like looking at XML:

[image]

You can read about the `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` wait [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/sos_scheduler_yield/). A good layman's explanation is that your query was only able to execute on a CPU for 6639 ms. It spent 66883 ms on a queue waiting to get on a CPU. Based on your description of the problem ("executing the view only takes 6 seconds"), you have a server performance issue instead of a query performance issue. Of course, there may be ways to make the query use even less CPU, but I would approach this problem by verifying that the server has the correct number of CPU cores/DTUs/whatever and by looking at the queries that use the most CPU on the server. Your query could run almost 12X faster if there was less load on the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the same as what you have.

Yes the view runs in 6 seconds but the query is making many calls to the view.

The solution may be [indexed views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017).  Put an index on the group by columns.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TopAdsDisplaySumaryView] AS
SELECT  client.Id AS ClientId,      -- (PK, int, not null)
        client.PartnerId,           -- (FK, int, not null)
        adsPict.Id AS AdsPictureId, -- (PK, int, not null)
        adsPict.ImageName           -- (nvarchar(max), null)
FROM    dbo.Machines AS machine 
INNER JOIN dbo.MachineGroups AS machineGroups 
        ON machineGroups.Id = machine.MachineGroupId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Clients AS client 
        ON client.Id = machineGroups.ClientId 
INNER JOIN dbo.DisplyadAds AS displayAds 
        ON displayAds.MachineId = machine.Id 
INNER JOIN dbo.AdsPictures AS adsPict 
        ON adsPict.Id = displayAds.AdsPictureId  

SELECT TOP 5
       adsSum.PartnerId as PartnerId,          -- client
       adsSum.ClientId as ClientId,            -- client
       adsSum.AdsPictureId as AdsPictureId,    -- adsPict
       adsSum.ImageName as ImageName,          -- adsPict
       count(*) as TotalDisplay
FROM [dbo].[TopAdsDisplaySumaryView] adsSum
GROUP BY adsSum.PartnerId, adsSum.ClientId, adsSum.AdsPictureId, adsSum.ImageName
ORDER BY TotalDisplay DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems impossible to create an index in a view, since this view may return multiple rows of `PartnerId`, `ClientId`, and `AdsPictureId`.

Answer (score 0):

Try add indexes that will assist in the Grouping.

Start with:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON dbo.Clients(PartnerId)
```

Check out this article by [Erik Darling](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/indexing-for-group-by/) it shows how to deal with the expensive Hash Match Aggregate that is costing 34% on your plan.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't make any changes.